# Decomposing a summation

Tags: summation

How is it possible to go from 1 to 2?
I can't include images in questions, so I've linked to them.

$$R\cdot l\cdot\sum_{t=t_0}^{t_1}\frac{1}{L(t)}$$
$$R\cdot l\cdot\left(\sum_{t=0}^{t_1}\frac{1}{L(t)}-\sum_{t=0}^{t_0}\frac{1}{L(t)}\right)$$

From my understanding, the top limit is inclusive, so wouldn't the two terms when $t = 0$ cancel out in the second equation, thus changing the initial form?

Comment: Hi there, please attach images as images, rather than hyperlinks. And it is better if you use [MathJax formatting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Yes, the summand for $t=0$ is supposed to cancel. There is, however, a different problem. The $t=t_0$ term does cancel and it is supposed to exist in the first formula. It should be $R\cdot l\cdot\left(\sum_{t=0}^{t_1}\frac{1}{L(t)}-\sum_{t=0}^{t_0-1}\frac{1}{L(t)}\right)$.